# Remove offending extra output from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having an issue with the JSON response I'm receiving from a server. The response is prepended with the following output:

```
    <!--<h1>Welcome..!</h1><br />
         <div id="root" style="border: 1px solid red; padding : 25px; width: 800px;">This is 'root' div.</div>
-->
```

**Example from my console:**
[image: screenshot of browser console showing a string that contains whitespace and HTML followed by JSON serialized data]

My JavaScript for fetching the data is:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments`) //console.log
```

I need to remove the leading non-JSON text so that I can parse and use the response. How do I do this?

Comment: Don't fix what arrives in the browser. You are being sent this from your server. Fix your server so it sends you proper JSON, not JSON encoded as a string with a piece of HTML at the beginning.

Comment: @JeremyThille That assumes he has control over what the server sends

Comment: Absolutely, but we have no info about this, so I assume that's the case

Comment: @JeremyThille I think when you don't have info, you shouldn't assume anything.  Inquire, sure, assume, absolutely not.

Comment: I'll go along with @JeremyThille's assumption, emboldened by the `localhost` in the example AJAX. And if that assumption is true, then his suggestion is absolutely correct. If it's not, then the OP should file a _critical_ bug with the provider of whatever API is being consumed.

Comment: @Dexygen that's a good advice, so OP : _if_ you have control over your server, fix your server :)

Comment: @JAAulde You'd STILL be wrong to go along with the assumption as I often run two applications on localhost -- back-end code provided by the back-end development team, and then my front-end code.  But I agree then about reporting the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should figure out, why the welcome text is displayed.

if you still just want to remove the first text from the json, you should do something like this

```js
var json = "any text, not containing curly or square brackets[{data: \"json\"}]";

// concentrate on this
json = json.replace(/^[^{[]+/, "");

document.body.innerText = json;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this answer will break for responses where single values like `true`, `false`, `null`, `0`, etc. were JSON encoded. Example, `JSON.stringify(true).replace(/^[^{[]+/, "");` will produce an empty string.

Comment: you're right. I was expecting him to just remove this text from this specific response. for any other type than object or array it is very hard to remove, because you can't really know what's coming in and what is correct

Comment: that's nice and you're prob right, but doesn't answer the question.